# How to encode additional information when representing data in higher dimensions?

Tags: general-topology, mathematical-modeling

Suppose we have an $n$-dimenosional vector $\vec{x}\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ representing an image. Furthermore, assume there is a function $f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{m}$ describing some sort of transformation on $\vec{x}$ (e.g. affine transformation), where $m\gg n$. If we assume that the vector $\vec{x}$ encodes some objects like for instance cars, how would we econde those prior information about objects (i.e. geometry, shapes, sizes) into the higher-dimensional representation of $\vec{x}$? Is there a way to preserve or encode information such as shapes and geometry about objects in higher-dimensions (topological spaces)?

To be more precise think of $f$ representing a composition of parametric differentiable non-linear functions such that $f:= f_{n}(\theta_{n}),\circ\ldots\circ,f_{1}(\theta_{1})$. For the sake of argument suppose that $f$ is a neural network which embeds $\vec{x}$ in a manifold. To my understanding (please correct me if I'm wrong) regardless of $f$ data such as $\vec{x}$ are encoded as points in a manifold (probably equiped with some properties) or higher dimenisonal spasce? Hence, the question is it possible to encode additional information about what $\vec{x}$ represents?

Thanks!

Comment: If you're discussing topological spaces, I think that you'd first have to define the topology that you're using before discussing vectors in the topology.  Since you're assuming vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, that usually means you're using the open ball topology.  But then a "car" is not obviously an object in the open ball topology, and so you'd have to explain what you mean by describing a car in that topology.

Comment: Could you make your question more precise, e.g. what is it that you are specifically trying to do, and in what sense do you mean that geometry, shape and size are encoded in $\mathbb R^n$? And btw, topological spaces don't have a notion of dimension in general.

Comment: @Lance - Topological spaces do have a notion of dimension. See, for example, here: 
http://math.ucr.edu/~res/miscpapers/top-dimension-theory.pdf

Comment: @uniquesolution - Thank you, I wasn't aware of this Lebesgue covering dimension. Is it standard? I've never seen/heard of it before.

Comment: I think that [sparse dictionary learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_dictionary_learning) is one approach to doing this. You represent an image as a sparse linear combination of elements of an overcomplete dictionary. Each atom in the dictionary represents a possible pattern that might appear in an image. I think a nonlinear version of this idea, using neural networks, is the [sparse autoencoder](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoencoder#Sparse_autoencoder).

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends to a large extent on the properties of the function $f$. The Euclidean space has several possible frameworks of structure: linear, topological, metric, differentiable-manifold, and algebraic, as well as fruitful combination of some of these. Information encoded in an $n$-dimensional vector could be different from information encoded in another $n$-dimensional vector, for several reasons: it could be "far" in a metric sense, or it could be nonequivalent with respect to a certain algebraic or topological equivalence relation. Thus, in order to provide a reasonable answer to your question, you should provide some information about $f$, in terms of how does it correspond to any of the above structures: is it linear? is it continuous? is differentiable? is it a group-homomorphism? etc.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I've edited the question to makes things more clear. Please let me know if still that doesn't help? Thanks in advance!